# What's the npm registry URL for a scoped package?

Tags: node.js, npm

There's an underlying API to npm - registry.npmjs.org (amongst others). The docs are here - https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md

If I want to query a package (eg, express) then the URL is https://registry.npmjs.org/express/.

However, if I want to query a scoped package (eg, @types/node), I can find it in the search endpoint (https://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/search?text=@types/node), but when I hit https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node I get a 404.

As this is not documented, does anyone know what the URL is for public scoped packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform url encoding for a scoped packages in npm repository.

```
@types/node as @types%2Fnode
```

Exact URL https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2Fnode

Comment: You know, I thought I'd tried that. I feel a bit thick now :)

Thanks very much